# Passing list of subnet as a parameter to nested CloudFormation Templates fails with an error

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am trying to launch a stack by passing a list of subnet IDs and VPC IDs as parameter to a nested stack. However the stack fails with an error as below. Can anybody please suggest how to pass a list in nested stack.
Parameters section of parent stack
[image: Parent stack]
Resources section of parent stack
[image: Parent stack resources]
Error
[image: Error]
[image: Child template]

Comment: You would need to also show the relevant sections of your code.

Comment: I have added Parameter section and Resources section of Parent Template. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @Alex Harvey. What is the `Server-Stack` expecting? A list of subnet-ids or single subnet-id?

Looking at your parent stack your `PublicSubnetIds` & `PrivateSubnetIds` are declared as lists. If you meant to pass a list to your `Server-Stack`, you have to declare them as type `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` in `Parameters` section of your `Server-Stack`

Comment: Server-Stack expects list of subnet-ids. I have passed List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id> in the Parent stack and Child stack but while referring it in Child stack I get above error.

Comment: Need to see you child stack

Comment: Added child template snippet above.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. On 2nd thoughts I am not sure what error you are getting (error image seems to be cut) or why the need to paste images instead of actual text.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is passing `Ref! PublicSubnetIds` of type `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` into a field that apparently expects data of type `AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id`.

To select the nth element of a list use the intrinsic function [Fn::Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html), i.e.

```
SubnetId1: !Select [0, !Ref PublicSubnetIds]
SubnetId2: !Select [1, !Ref PublicSubnetIds]
```

Comment: Do I need to add this in parent template?